# I am trying to fix my menu when a user is loggedin or log out

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react js and trying to figure out how can I display different buttons based on the login. I have the const loggedIn but now trying to figure out how to include it in return.

```
   const classes = useStyles();
  const account = useSelector((state) => state.account);
  const { isLoggedIn } = account;

  return (
    <Toolbar disableGutters className={classes.toolbar} {...rest}>
      <div className={classes.flexGrow} />
      <Hidden smDown>
        <List className={classes.navigationContainer}>
         
            <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              color="textSecondary"
              className={classes.listItemText}
              component="a"
              href="/register"
            >
              Sign up
            </Typography>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <Button
              size="large"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              component="a"
              target="blank"
              href="/login"
              className={classes.listItemButton}
            >
              Log In
            </Button>
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <Button
              size="large"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              component="a"
              target="blank"
              href=“/dashboard”
              className={classes.listItemButton}
            >
              Dashboard
            </Button>
            </ListItem>

        </List>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden mdUp>
        <IconButton
          className={classes.iconButton}
          onClick={onSidebarOpen}
          aria-label="Menu"
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Hidden>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};
```

When isLoggedIn is true I want dashboard to show when is false I want to show login and signup. Any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScript's ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to select a value based on criteria (in your case, the isLoggedIn variable).
Then, you can inject it into your JSX code by wrapping the expression with curly braces.

```js
return (
    <div>
        {isLoggedIn ? <DashboardComponent /> : <LoginSignupComponent />}
    </div>
);
```

React's official conditional rendering documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: done this but I am trying to figure out how to include two components together.  {isLoggedIn ? <DashboardComponent /> : <LoginComponent /> <SignupComponent>}

Comment: Wrap them with a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html): <><Component1/><Component2/></>